# Keep table width of two scrollable table same and the header stay put

Tags: html, css

I have a table (table2) inside the  of a table (table1). 
table1 inside div "outer" and table2 inside div "inner".
I want to enable scroll-x for div "outer" and enable scroll-y for div "inner" so when the table1 scroll vertically, the header will stay put. I did it and got what I want, but the column width of table2 can't be set even if I set it in a class (using CSS) or set the width in td. I also tried using colgroup but still same. I also tried using one table for all (table1 and table2) with different div but the header table can't stay put, even if it can but the width can't be set as I want. All method I've tried just give me that problem, the header can't stay put or the width size can't be set.

[my table now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2r0c.png)

How can the column width of the table2 is same as table1?

Here is my code

```
<div class="outernew">
    <table style="width:1250px; margin-left:10px; margin-right:10px;" cellspacing=1>
    <thead>
        <tr bgcolor="#EAEAE9">
            <th height="60" rowspan="4" bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange col1">No</th>
            <th rowspan="4" bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange col2">Area</th>
            <th rowspan="4" bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange col3">Site Name</th>
            <th rowspan="4" bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange col4">Alamat</th>
            <th rowspan="4" bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange col5">Antenna</th>
            <th rowspan="4" bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange col6">TSI</th>
            <th rowspan="3" colspan="2" bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange col7head">Periode</th>

        <?
            $jml_asr = $db->query("select ...");
            for($a=0; $a<count($jml_asr); $a++){
        ?>

            <th height="30" colspan="42" bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange col8head"><? echo $jml_asr[$a]['assurance_name']; ?></th>
            <th bgcolor="ffffff" class="col9"></th>

        <?
            }
        ?>

        </tr>

        <tr>

        <?
            for($a=0; $a<count($jml_asr); $a++){
        ?>

            <th colspan="6" bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange">Flexas</th>
            <th colspan="6" bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange">RSMDCC</th>
            <th colspan="6" bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange">Others</th>
            <th colspan="6" bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange">TSFWD</th>
            <th colspan="6" bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange">All Risk</th>
            <th colspan="6" bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange">EQVET</th>
            <th colspan="6" bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange">Total AR + EQVET</th>
            <th width="5" bgcolor="ffffff"></th>

        <?
            }
        ?>

        </tr>

        <tr bgcolor="#EAEAE9">

        <?
            for($a=0; $a<count($jml_asr); $a++){
                for($r=0; $r<7; $r++){
        ?>

            <th colspan="2" bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange">Rate</th>
            <th colspan="2" bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange">Discount</th>
            <th colspan="2" bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange">Result</th>

        <?      } ?>

            <th bgcolor="ffffff"></th>

        <?  }
        ?>

        </tr>

        <tr bgcolor="#EAEAE9">
            <th bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange">Start</th>
            <th bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange">End</th>

        <?
            for($a=0; $a<count($jml_asr); $a++){
                for($s=0; $s<21; $s++){
        ?>

            <th bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange">%</th>
            <th bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange">IDR</th>

        <?      } ?>

            <th bgcolor="ffffff"></th>

        <?  }
        ?>

        </tr>

        <tr>

        <?
            $sum = $db->query("select ... ");

        ?>

            <th bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange">&Sigma;</th>
            <th bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange"></th>
            <th bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange"><? echo $sum[0]['total']; ?></th>
            <th bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange"></th>
            <th bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange"><? echo $sum[0]['sum_antenna'] ?></th>
            <th bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange"><? echo strstr($sum_tsi, ',', true); ?></th>
            <th bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange"></th>
            <th bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange"></th>

        <?
            for($a=0; $a<count($jml_asr); $a++){

                $sum_avg = $db->query("select ... ");

        ?>

            <th bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange"><? echo number_format($sum_avg[0]['avg_flexas'], 3, ',', '.')."%"; ?></th>
            <th bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange"><? echo strstr($sum_flexas_idr, ',', true); ?></th>
            <th bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange"></th>
            <th bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange"></th>
            <th bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange"><? echo number_format($sum_avg[0]['avg_flexasafter'], 3, ',', '.')."%"; ?></th>
            <th bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange"><? echo strstr($sum_flexasafter_idr, ',', true); ?></th>
            <th bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange"><? echo number_format($sum_avg[0]['avg_rsmdcc'], 3, ',', '.')."%"; ?></th>
            <th bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange"><? echo strstr($sum_rsmdcc_idr, ',', true); ?></th>
            <th bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange"></th>
            <th bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange"></th>
            <th bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange"><? echo number_format($sum_avg[0]['avg_rsmdccafter'], 3, ',', '.')."%"; ?></th>
            <th bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange"><? echo strstr($sum_rsmdccafter_idr, ',', true); ?></th>
            <th bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange"><? echo number_format($sum_avg[0]['avg_others'], 3, ',', '.')."%"; ?></th>
            <th bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange"><? echo strstr($sum_others_idr, ',', true); ?></th>
            <th bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange"></th>
            <th bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange"></th>
            <th bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange"><? echo number_format($sum_avg[0]['avg_othersafter'], 3, ',', '.')."%"; ?></th>
            <th bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange"><? echo strstr($sum_othersafter_idr, ',', true); ?></th>
            <th bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange"><? echo number_format($sum_avg[0]['avg_tsfwd'], 3, ',', '.')."%"; ?></th>
            <th bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange"><? echo strstr($sum_tsfwd_idr, ',', true); ?></th>
            <th bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange"></th>
            <th bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange"></th>
            <th bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange"><? echo number_format($sum_avg[0]['avg_tsfwdafter'], 3, ',', '.')."%"; ?></th>
            <th bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange"><? echo strstr($sum_tsfwdafter_idr, ',', true); ?></th>
            <th bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange"><? echo number_format($sum_avg[0]['avg_allrisk'], 3, ',', '.')."%"; ?></th>
            <th bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange"><? echo strstr($sum_allrisk_idr, ',', true); ?></th>
            <th bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange"></th>
            <th bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange"></th>
            <th bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange"><? echo number_format($sum_avg[0]['avg_allriskafter'], 3, ',', '.')."%"; ?></th>
            <th bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange"><? echo strstr($sum_allriskafter_idr, ',', true); ?></th>
            <th bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange"><? echo number_format($sum_avg[0]['avg_eqvet'], 3, ',', '.')."%"; ?></th>
            <th bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange"><? echo strstr($sum_eqvet_idr, ',', true); ?></th>
            <th bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange"></th>
            <th bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange"></th>
            <th bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange"><? echo number_format($sum_avg[0]['avg_eqvetafter'], 3, ',', '.')."%"; ?></th>
            <th bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange"><? echo strstr($sum_eqvetafter_idr, ',', true); ?></th>
            <th bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange"><? echo number_format($sum_avg[0]['avg_premi'], 3, ',', '.')."%"; ?></th>
            <th bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange"><? echo strstr($sum_premi_idr, ',', true); ?></th>
            <th bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange"></th>
            <th bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange"></th>
            <th bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange"><? echo number_format($sum_avg[0]['avg_premiafter'], 3, ',', '.')."%"; ?></th>
            <th bgcolor="#EAEAE9" align="center" class="defaultboldorange"><? echo strstr($sum_premiafter_idr, ',', true); ?></th>

            <th bgcolor="ffffff"></th>
        <?
            }
        ?>

        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    <tr><td colspan="<? echo (8+(43*count($jml_asr)));?>" >
    <div class="innernew">
    <table style="width:100%; height:100px;" cellspacing=1>
      <?
        $number=1;
        for ($count_all_data=0; $count_all_data<count($get_all_data); $count_all_data++){                  
      ?>    

        <tr bgcolor="#E9F3F1">
            <td class="Default col1" align="center" height="20"><? echo $number; ?></td>
            <td class="Default col2" align="center"><? echo $get_all_data[$count_all_data]['city_name']; ?></td>
            <td class="Default col3" align="left"><? echo $get_all_data[$count_all_data]['site_name']; ?></td>
            <td class="Default col4" align="center" style="white-space:nowrap; overflow:hidden; text-overflow:ellipsis;"><? echo $get_all_data[$count_all_data]['site_address']; ?></td>
            <td class="Default col5" align="center"><? echo $get_all_data[$count_all_data]['antenna']; ?></td>
            <td class="Default col6" align="center"><? echo strstr(number_format(($get_all_data[$count_all_data]['TSI']/1000000), 3, ',', '.'), ',', true); ?></td>
            <td class="Default col7" align="center"><? echo date('j M y', strtotime($get_all_data[$count_all_data]['date_start'])); ?></td>
            <td class="Default col7" align="center"><? echo date('j M y', strtotime($get_all_data[$count_all_data]['date_end'])); ?></td>

        <?
            for($a=0; $a<count($jml_asr); $a++){
            $get_data = $db->query("select ... ");

        ?>

            <td class="Default col8" align="center"><? echo number_format($get_data[0]['flexas'], 5, ',', '.')."%"; ?></td>
            <td class="Default col8" align="center"><? echo strstr(number_format(($get_data[0]['flexas_idr']/1000), 3, ',', '.'), ',', true); ?></td>
            <td class="Default col8" align="center"><? echo number_format($get_data[0]['flexas_diskon'], 5, ',', '.')."%"; ?></td>
            <td class="Default col8" align="center"><? echo strstr(number_format(($get_data[0]['flexasdiskon_idr']/1000), 3, ',', '.'), ',', true); ?></td>
            <td class="Default col8" align="center"><? echo number_format($get_data[0]['flexas_afterdiskon'], 5, ',', '.')."%"; ?></td>
            <td class="Default col8" align="center"><? echo strstr(number_format(($get_data[0]['flexasafter_idr']/1000), 3, ',', '.'), ',', true); ?></td>

            <td class="Default col8" align="center"><? echo number_format($get_data[0]['rsmdcc'], 5, ',', '.')."%"; ?></td>
            <td class="Default col8" align="center"><? echo strstr(number_format(($get_data[0]['rsmdcc_idr']/1000), 3, ',', '.'), ',', true); ?></td>
            <td class="Default col8" align="center"><? echo number_format($get_data[0]['rsmdcc_diskon'], 5, ',', '.')."%"; ?></td>
            <td class="Default col8" align="center"><? echo strstr(number_format(($get_data[0]['rsmdccdiskon_idr']/1000), 3, ',', '.'), ',', true); ?></td>
            <td class="Default col8" align="center"><? echo number_format($get_data[0]['rsmdcc_afterdiskon'], 5, ',', '.')."%"; ?></td>
            <td class="Default col8" align="center"><? echo strstr(number_format(($get_data[0]['rsmdccafter_idr']/1000), 3, ',', '.'), ',', true); ?></td>

            <td class="Default col8" align="center"><? echo number_format($get_data[0]['others'], 5, ',', '.')."%"; ?></td>
            <td class="Default col8" align="center"><? echo strstr(number_format(($get_data[0]['others_idr']/1000), 3, ',', '.'), ',', true); ?></td>
            <td class="Default col8" align="center"><? echo number_format($get_data[0]['others_diskon'], 5, ',', '.')."%"; ?></td>
            <td class="Default col8" align="center"><? echo strstr(number_format(($get_data[0]['othersdiskon_idr']/1000), 3, ',', '.'), ',', true); ?></td>
            <td class="Default col8" align="center"><? echo number_format($get_data[0]['others_afterdiskon'], 5, ',', '.')."%"; ?></td>
            <td class="Default col8" align="center"><? echo strstr(number_format(($get_data[0]['othersafter_idr']/1000), 3, ',', '.'), ',', true); ?></td>

            <td class="Default col8" align="center"><? echo number_format($get_data[0]['tsfwd'], 5, ',', '.')."%"; ?></td>
            <td class="Default col8" align="center"><? echo strstr(number_format(($get_data[0]['tsfwd_idr']/1000), 3, ',', '.'), ',', true); ?></td>
            <td class="Default col8" align="center"><? echo number_format($get_data[0]['tsfwd_diskon'], 5, ',', '.')."%"; ?></td>
            <td class="Default col8" align="center"><? echo strstr(number_format(($get_data[0]['tsfwddiskon_idr']/1000), 3, ',', '.'), ',', true); ?></td>
            <td class="Default col8" align="center"><? echo number_format($get_data[0]['tsfwd_afterdiskon'], 5, ',', '.')."%"; ?></td>
            <td class="Default col8" align="center"><? echo strstr(number_format(($get_data[0]['tsfwdafter_idr']/1000), 3, ',', '.'), ',', true); ?></td>

            <td class="Default col8" align="center"><? echo number_format($get_data[0]['allrisk'], 5, ',', '.')."%"; ?></td>
            <td class="Default col8" align="center"><? echo strstr(number_format(($get_data[0]['allrisk_idr']/1000), 3, ',', '.'), ',', true); ?></td>
            <td class="Default col8" align="center"><? echo number_format($get_data[0]['allrisk_diskon'], 5, ',', '.')."%"; ?></td>
            <td class="Default col8" align="center"><? echo strstr(number_format(($get_data[0]['allriskdiskon_idr']/1000), 3, ',', '.'), ',', true); ?></td>
            <td class="Default col8" align="center"><? echo number_format($get_data[0]['allrisk_afterdiskon'], 5, ',', '.')."%"; ?></td>
            <td class="Default col8" align="center"><? echo strstr(number_format(($get_data[0]['allriskafter_idr']/1000), 3, ',', '.'), ',', true); ?></td>

            <td class="Default col8" align="center"><? echo number_format($get_data[0]['eqvet'], 5, ',', '.')."%"; ?></td>
            <td class="Default col8" align="center"><? echo strstr(number_format(($get_data[0]['eqvet_idr']/1000), 3, ',', '.'), ',', true); ?></td>
            <td class="Default col8" align="center"><? echo number_format($get_data[0]['eqvet_diskon'], 5, ',', '.')."%"; ?></td>
            <td class="Default col8" align="center"><? echo strstr(number_format(($get_data[0]['eqvetdiskon_idr']/1000), 3, ',', '.'), ',', true); ?></td>
            <td class="Default col8" align="center"><? echo number_format($get_data[0]['eqvet_afterdiskon'], 5, ',', '.')."%"; ?></td>
            <td class="Default col8" align="center"><? echo strstr(number_format(($get_data[0]['eqvetafter_idr']/1000), 3, ',', '.'), ',', true); ?></td>

            <td class="Default col8" align="center"><? echo number_format($get_data[0]['premi'], 5, ',', '.')."%"; ?></td>
            <td class="Default col8" align="center"><? echo strstr(number_format(($get_data[0]['premi_idr']/1000), 3, ',', '.'), ',', true); ?></td>
            <td class="Default col8" align="center"><? echo number_format($get_data[0]['premi_diskon'], 5, ',', '.')."%"; ?></td>
            <td class="Default col8" align="center"><? echo strstr(number_format(($get_data[0]['premidiskon_idr']/1000), 3, ',', '.'), ',', true); ?></td>
            <td class="Default col8" align="center"><? echo number_format($get_data[0]['premi_afterdiskon'], 5, ',', '.')."%"; ?></td>
            <td class="Default col8" align="center"><? echo strstr(number_format(($get_data[0]['premiafter_idr']/1000), 3, ',', '.'), ',', true); ?></td>

            <td class="col9" bgcolor="ffffff"></td>
        <?
            }
        ?>

        </tr>

        <? $number+=1; } ?>
        <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        </table>
        </div>
    </td></tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS

```
 .defaultboldorange {
  font-family : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size : 12px;
  font-weight : bold;
  line-height: 13px;
  color : #e84e0f;
}
.default {
  font-family : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size : 12px;
  font-weight : normal;
  line-height: 13px;
  color : #666666;
}
.col1 { width:40px; }
.col2 { width:60px; }
.col3 { width:300px; }
.col4 { width:150px; }
.col5 { width:50px; }
.col6 { width:50px; }
.col7head { width:120px; }
.col7 { width:58px; }
.col8head { 
    width:2436px;
    /*width:2700px;*/ 
    }
.col8 { width:58px; }
.col9 { width:5px; }

.outernew { 
    width:1250px;
    overflow-x:scroll;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    height:300px;
}
.innernew {
    overflow-y:scroll;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    height:200px;
}
```

I didn't set the width for .innernew because it will be like this
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftcBY.png)

Any ideas? Thank you. It'll help me so much..

Comment: You can change `<? echo` by `<?=`

Comment: @MathieuLescaudron nothing change :(

Comment: Yes, it's just for a better look in the code

Comment: @MathieuLescaudron oh thank you. i learn something new :)

Comment: np see also http://web-profile.net/php/basic/php-for-endfor/

Comment: If you know about CSS, why are there `align` attributes on each and every one of your <td>s. Also, some of the `bgcolor` values are misspelled.